# What does this relative sentence modify?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But Max Little at Aston University in Birmingham, UK, who explores the use of voice-processing algorithms to predict the severity of Parkinson’s, isn’t convinced by the big data approach. “I’m deeply sceptical of efforts **that naively believe you can simply accumulate more data and that will do the job,” he says.**

From:
https://www.newscientist.com/article/2120426-health-insurer-calls-analysed-for-signs-of-disease-in-your-voice/

Is this sentence too colloquial  to be grammatical？ I don't understand which part "that naively believe you can simply accumulate more data and that will do the job" modifies.

Thanks if you would help.

Comment: Yes. it's fine. The relative clause modifies "efforts". Generally, relatives modify the nearest noun or nominal.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your confirmation. I was confused because I wasn't familiar with the use of "efforts"with an inanimate subject.

Comment: Yes, it does seem an odd use of "efforts", but I think we have to assume that the writer knows what he's talking about, even if we don't!

Comment: It seems to say that "efforts believe". It's grammatical, but it's a little slipshod semantically.